# iPhone XCode programming: execute code when change tab in a tab bar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing a simple tab bar application for school.
It has 3 tabs.
One of them plays music in streaming and I would like to stop the music playing when the user changes the tab. Is this possible? and How? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `UITabViewController` delegate method:

```
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

And you should be able to do what you want.  There's also

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
```

if you want to know *before* the tab changes.

Comment: Do you mean `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 2):

As Carl says, this is possible. However, if I were to develop such application (and actually, I am), I would use the `viewWillDisappear` method of my `UIViewController` (and I am). That way you keep the logic separated between your implementations.